# How to use SHA-512 in terminal?

Tags: encryption, openssl

I do not understand this problem. I tried my code down below. `It says,"can only sign or verify one file."`

Instructions:
Using the hash function SHA‐512 and the key generated in Step 5, 
sign the ciphertext `cipher.bin` produced in Step 3 and the encrypted session key 
`cipherSK.bin` from Step 4. Output the signatures to files named `sigCipher.bin` and 
`sigSK.bin` respectively.

This is what I tried.

```
openssl -sha512 -sign cipher.bin cipherSK.bin -out sigCipher.bin sigSK.bin
```

Let me know if you need the whole instructions.

Comment: how dit you generate the key?

Comment: RSA encryption key encKey.bin. It was given.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Yes, this is homework.

Comment: **Hint:** Google `OpenSSL sign file with RSA`

Comment: I read the whole article. I still do not know what to do?  I am getting "unable to load unable to load key file"

Comment: You really should read your course materials and consult with your instructor regarding this.